# C# как можно сократить код и сделать более гибким

Tags: c#

Есть много методов у которых один и тот же код с проверкой на подключение к устройству, как сделать более универсально и компактно что бы не писать один и тот же код в каждом методе

```
        var con = ClientConnectionToDevice[Context.ConnectionId];
        await con.ConnectionDeviceAsync();
        if (await con.СheckConnectionTelnet())
        { 
          тут выполняется нужный код метода;
        }
```

Comment: вынеси эту часть в метод и передавай в него делегат

Comment: Да и просто вынести этот код в отдельный метод уже лучше будет

Comment: @Grundy а можно пример ?